# I want to connect a variable from a directive to a component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-components

Every directive has a

```
// Modules and Components
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Directive
import { DraggableDirective } from '../draggable/draggable.directive';

// Interfaces
import { Position } from '../../../../interfaces/draggable-system/move-position';

/**
 * Allows to move the objects.
 */

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMovable]'
})
export class MovableDirective extends DraggableDirective {

  // ********** DECLARATIONS **********//

  // Overview of the Inputs, Outputs and HostBindings
  @Input('appMovable') set movable(movable: boolean) {
    this.enabled = movable;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.moving') moving = false;

  // Check the positions
  position: Position = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  private startPosition: Position;
  private reset = false;

  constructor(
    public element: ElementRef,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    super();
  }

  // Use HostBindings and HostListener

  @HostBinding('style.transform') get transform(): SafeStyle {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
      `translateX(${this.position.x}px) translateY(${this.position.y}px)`
    );
  }

  @HostListener('dragStart', ['$event']) onDragStart(event: PointerEvent): void {
    this.moving = true;
    this.startPosition = {
      x: event.clientX - this.position.x,
      y: event.clientY - this.position.y
    };
  }

  @HostListener('dragMove', ['$event']) onDragMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
    this.position = {
      x: event.clientX - this.startPosition.x,
      y: event.clientY - this.startPosition.y,
    };
  }

  @HostListener('dragEnd') onDragEnd(): void {
    this.moving = false;

    if (this.reset) {
      this.position = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      };
    }
  }
}
```

I need to bind a variable from this directive into a component. How do I do this?  This directive consists of events where the x axis and y axis are detected during the mouse event. the boolean variable movable should be identified somehow.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'moving' of undefined

moving is also a boolean variable that I needed connected to the component

Answer (score 2):

If your directive export as

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMovable]',
  exportAs: 'appMovable'
})
```

When you use a template reference variable you can indicate the "exportAs" and use it (really event you can call to a function if you want)

```
<div appMovable #d="appMovable">{{d.movable}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solution:

) Use a service to store a global variable which will be updated as MovableDirective is called. For that, you'll need to inject your service in your Directive.

) Or you can use @Output in your directive to bubble up movable in your Component

```
export class MovableDirective extends DraggableDirective {
[...]
@Output()
eventToBubbleUp = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
[...]
onDragEnd() {
    [...]
    this.eventToBubbleUp.emit(movable);
}
}
```

And you may call it this way

```
  <div [...] appMovable (eventToBubbleUp)="toDo(movable)"></div >
```

Comment: It still doesnt work.  If I make  <div appMovable (eventToBubbleUp)="movableDirective.onDragMove(movableDirective) ">, the button, which is the child of the div vanishes.

Comment: That's not how you would use the output method. The toDo(movable) method is inside your component, check https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component for more info.